# Surjective homomorphisms between braid groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, low-dimensional-topology, braid-groups

There cannot be a surjective homomorphism $B_2 \to B_n$ for any $n > 2$ because $B_2$ is commutative and $B_n$ is not. It seems plausible that if $m < n$, there cannot be a surjective homomorphism $B_m \to B_n$.

If $m>n$, there are surjective maps $B_m \to B_n$ obtained by forgetting a certain number of strands, but these are not homomorphisms: e.g., if $f: B_3 \to B_2$ is the map forgetting the third strand, then $f(\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \sigma_1) = \sigma_1$, but $f(\sigma_1) \cdot f(\sigma_2) \cdot f(\sigma_1) = \sigma_1^2$. Here, $\sigma_i$ is the braid swapping the $i$-th and the $(i+1)$-st strand using a single positive crossing.

How do these observations generalize? I.e., under what conditions on $m,n \geq 2$ does there exist a surjective homomorphism $B_m \to B_n$? My suspicion is that this requires $m = n$ or, similar to the case of symmetric groups, $(m,n) = (4,3)$, is this true?

**Edit**: I also posted this on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/365463/147690) since this may be harder than it looks. In the comments there, a solution for the case $m > n$ has turned up in the literature (Theorem 3.1 in [Lin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404528.pdf)). Any thoughts on the case $m < n$ are very much appreciated.

Comment: As $S_n$ is a quotient of $B_n$, we can ask if there is a surjective homomorphism $B_m\to S_n$. If not that would be a barrier to a surjective map $B_m\to S_n$. I can't see how to prove that though....